# 'set-env' error when trying to build Android app using GitHub Actions - don't understand how to use Environment Files in this circumstance

Tags: android, github-actions

I am new to GitHub Actions and want to build and deploy my Android app to "internal testing" at the Google Play store. I have seen some good articles on it, but have been running into the 'set-env' error. I have followed the link but still do not understand how to apply it to my specific use case.

> The `set-env` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment
> Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the
> `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For
> more information see:
> https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

Here is the error:
[image]

There seems to be some good examples without the environment files, which seems like the right way to go. I am following [this](https://www.valueof.io/blog/deploying-to-google-play-using-github-actions), [this](https://medium.com/@niraj_prajapati/automate-android-app-publishing-on-play-store-using-github-actions-554de7801c36#:%7E:text=Automate%20Android%20App%20Publishing%20on%20Play%20Store%20using,Deploy%20to%20Play%20Store.%20...%20More%20items...%20), and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVLyADb8rQc&t=580s). All have some simple steps, but this is where I am having the problem:

```
- name: set up JDK 1.8
  uses: actions/setup-java@v1.4.2
  with:
    java-version: 1.8
```

My yaml file looks like this:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.1
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1.4.2
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
        
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
      
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

I need to get through this before I can tackle the signing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an updated version of the [actions/setup-java](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) step, like:

```
    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.1
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@
      with:
        distribution: 'zulu' # See 'Supported distributions' for available options
        java-version: '8'
```